# Open second JFrame and components don't show

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

Before you say something, i know the implications of having more than one JFrame. I'm kinda delayed and i need to add the components manually.

So, i open a JFrame that i have designed with a button click:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

   JFrame DataCalc = new JFrame();
   DataCalc.setVisible(true); 
   DataCalc.setSize(500, 500);
   DataCalc.setLocationRelativeTo(null);   
}
```

Then the JFrame shows up but doesn't show my components. I read that if i setVisible before adding components they won't show, but they're already there cause i designed them.

If i change my code and add the setSize and setLocation like the following code, nothing happens besides the JFrame opening.

```
public DataCalc() {
    this.setSize(500, 500);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    initComponents();
}
```

Sry for the post, i'll edit my post if you need more info.

Comment: 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
JFrame DataCalc = new JFrame();
```

Should be:

```
JFrame dataCalc = new DataCalc(); // use the CUSTOM frame!
```

Comment: Well. I think i'm going to delete this post lol. Thank you !!

Comment: 2nd pair of eyes never hurts. ;)